# Denied permission to save a project in new version of QGIS 3.10.7

Tags: qgis

I have just downloaded QGIS 3.10.7 and when I open a project and make any changes and try to save it I get a message saying I "don't have permission to save in this location".  I also can not toggle editing on any layer.  When I use my 3.4.9 version I can save anywhere and toggle editing no problem.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Where are you saving the project file?